# users see my SMS messages as coming from '1010100001'

Tags: php, email, sms, header

In my application, I ask the user to enter their cell and select their provider. I append the provider's email and create the message and fire via php.mail()

The problem is that no matter what the header info is, the message comes from '1010100001' on some phones (like AT&T and the iPhone). When testing on my Verizon phone, I get the proper email address as the sender.

Any idea how I can send a clearer message?

Comment: to be clear, when I say "I append the provider's email", I meant to say that I'm creating an email address for the number using the unique email address for each carrier (example number@txt.att.net)

Comment: I think you should speak this with your sms provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not actually sending SMS messages, you're sending email messages and then trusting the carrier's email-to-sms gateway to "do the right thing."

To have better control over the SMS message, send the SMS message directly. For low volume, try [Twilio SMS Service](http://www.twilio.com/sms/)

Comment: Twilio looks great. Thanks Larry.